# Basic REST API in Ktor

Tags: rest, kotlin

I have written a basic REST endpoint in Ktor and would like some pointers.

**Application.kt**

```kotlin
@KtorExperimentalAPI
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(Authentication)
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {}
    }

    val materialRepository = MaterialRepository(environment.config.property("repo.ws").getString())

    routing {
        route("/api") {
            materials(materialRepository)
        }
    }
}
```

**MaterialResource.kt**

```kotlin
fun Route.materials(
    repo: MaterialRepository
) {
    route("/materials") {
        get("/{id}") {
            when (val idParam = call.parameters["id"]) {
                is String -> {
                    val id = idParam.toIntOrNull()
                    if (id == null) {
                        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    } else {
                        when (val material = repo.get(id)) {
                            is Material -> call.respond(material)
                            else -> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else -> call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MaterialRepository.kt**

```kotlin
class MaterialRepository(
    val wsInput: String
) {
    private var materials: Map<Int, Material> = HashMap()

    init {
        val jsonMaterials = Gson().fromJson(FileReader(wsInput), JsonMaterialTable::class.java)

        materials = jsonMaterials.rows.map {
            it.ID_WS to Material( /*...snip as the model is quite large...*/ )
        }.toMap()
    }

    fun get(id: Int): Material? {
        return materials[id]
    }
}
```

It feels like I am not using the whole power of kotlin and writing too much boilerplate. I am following the general guidelines of Kotlin and Ktor tutorials, but I still think this is too compliated and could be massively improved in terms of readability and general best practices before I continue writing the whole rest of the application.